# Building a website - Displaying product information

Tags: html, css, web

I am building an e-commerce website for a friend, I have some knowledge of HTML and CSS but I wouldn't class myself as advanced on the subject. I said I would do it as a favor/experience.

I just have a question about displaying multiple products information. My page currently has 12 items on it, do I need to create separate pages for each of those products with some information on it like so:

`www.shoes.com/trainers/shoe1.html` or `www.shoes.com/trainers/shoe2.html`

etc or is there a more efficient way of doing it.

I only ask because after looking around, the end urls do not contain pages like the above but look more like the following:

```
www.shoes.com/index.php?id_product=1025&controller=product
```

If anyone could help me out or point me somewhere I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The more efficient way is to use a CMS or cart - code that has already been written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your products in a **database**, if at all possible. This way you can use queries to sort and filter your products easily.
You are further looking for a **dynamic** website (http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php), using, for example, a .php script getting the desired data in MySQLi, for example (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp)

With this, you can create any lists and links using, for example, the product ID to refer to a product, like in your example ("?id_product=1025")

Your PHP script would look for id_product (`$_GET["id_product"]`) and use this to query your database and get the desired data.

Comment: Ah I did not realise this, I have used both MySQL and PHP before, but again, I only know enough about them rather than a lot. I will certainly try it, but the scope of this project might be out of my hands, thank you

Comment: Glad to help. Definitely, use already existing solutions, where applicable.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a dynamic website. You build a database with all the products, and create a "template" html page for how you want the product page to look like. For that, you will need to know a server side scripting language, like PHP or ASP.

If you are only familiar with HTML and CSS, your only option is building a "static" website, by creating an html page for each product. if there's alot of products it will be tedious and ineffective.

I would suggest a ready CMS, like wordpress for example. It has many "store" plugins you can download. one of the is Woocommerce. it's free to download but has paid plugins. I use it and i am happy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to paginate your data, to do this you have to create a database first then using any server side scripting language

for example this article guide you how to paginate your data with PHP

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

Answer (score 1):

I will just explain two types URL

```
www.shoes.com/trainers/shoe1.html

www.shoes.com/trainers/shoe2.html
```

The above method is a good way when you look at SEO point of view. Search Engine efficiently works with static URLs.

```
www.shoes.com/index.php?id_product=1025&controller=product
```

Second means, you are building a website with PHP and you are passing product id in URL as `?id_product=1025`. As you mentioned if you are creating E-Commerce website static page design will be a bad practice. Since you want to design each product page.

My Suggestion is you can try [Magento](http://magento.com/) which is having most of the features of E-Commerce Web.